# how can I make addition inner layer in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

New to tensorflow (and ai in general) - I am trying to build the simplest feed-forward model using tensorflow. I would like to run a sequential model on the fashion mnist data.
The only complication I am trying to perform is having some kind of middle layer that adds the former layer with the inputs.

I tried the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(x_train, y_train) , (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

x_train, x_test = x_train/255.0, x_test/255.0

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28))
inner_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(28*28, activation="relu")

hidden_layer_01 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")
hidden_layer_02 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")
hidden_layer_03 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")
hidden_layer_04 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")

hidden_layer_add = tf.keras.layers.add(28*28)([input_layer, inner_layer])

hidden_layer_dropout = tf.keras.Dropout(0.1)

output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)

model = tf.keras.Model(
    input_layer,
    hidden_layer_01,
    hidden_layer_02,
    inner_layer,
    hidden_layer_add,
    hidden_layer_03,
    hidden_layer_04,
    hidden_layer_dropout,
    output_layer
)

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

print("EVALUATING...")
model.evaluate(x_test,  y_test, verbose=2)
```

I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\PROJECTS\Python\pythonProject\fashionMnist01\main.py", line 30, in
>
> hidden_layer_add = tf.keras.layers.add(28*28)([input_layer, inner_layer])   File
> "D:\PROJECTS\Python\pythonProject\fashionMnist01\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\merging\add.py",
> line 92, in add
> return Add(**kwargs)(inputs)   File "D:\PROJECTS\Python\pythonProject\fashionMnist01\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py",
> line 70, in error_handler
> raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None   File "D:\PROJECTS\Python\pythonProject\fashionMnist01\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\merging\base_merge.py",
> line 84, in build
> if not isinstance(input_shape[0], tuple): IndexError: tuple index out of range

How can I make this work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some issue in your model definition. It looks like you're mixing functional and sequential APIs in your model definition. Please check the documentation of [functional](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/) and [sequential APIs](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/) to build the model.
There are mainly three ways (3 APIs) to build the model in keras, functional and sequential APIs are 2 of them. If you're wondering the difference of this APIs, check [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/model-sub-classing-and-custom-training-loop-from-scratch-in-tensorflow-2-cc1d4f10fb4e) blog post.And here is one possible way to build your broken model properly in functional API.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

input = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28))
x = keras.layers.Flatten()(input)
x = keras.layers.Dense(28*28, activation="relu")(x)

hid_a = keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(x)
hid_b = keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(hid_a)
hid_add = keras.layers.Concatenate()([hid_b, x])
hid_c = keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(hid_add)
hid_d = keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(hid_c)

hid_drop = keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(hid_d)
output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(10)(hid_drop)

model = keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output_layer)
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```